# Is it possible to Restrict access to specific projects in Oracle Service BUS (OSB 11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic11g, osb, oracle-service-bus

Can you please inform me, if OSB provides the option to allow access to specific projects via the OSB Console?
According to https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/ROLES/secroles.htm#ROLES181 , I know that I am provided the option to create custom users, roles and groups but I cannot see anywhere the option of giving partial access to the development of projects via the console. My options end in the restriction of menus/options in total, or upon a specific timeframe etc.

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: I believe you are stuck with assigning one of the 4 roles described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e15867/roles.htm#OSBAG463 which won't let you hide specific projects.

Comment: I agree. I expected this to be honest, I just wanted to verify it. Thanks for your time.